# how to run with --stacktrace flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I'm trying to run my application -that is working fine with my team members-
but i keep getting this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':package_info_plus'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info_plus-1.4.3+1\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':package_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':package_info_plus' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

Does anyone know the solution or can tell me how to view the stacktrace, I tried going to android studio-> settings-> compiler-> command
and i added --stacktrace but there is no changes in the run

Answer (score 0):

try `flutter run -d deviceid -v` , will give you an insight as to whats happening

You can also cd into the android folder and run `./gradlew build`

Comment: ./gradlew build is wrong. Correct way is .\gradlew build

Comment: ./gradlew for *nix based OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use --verbose to get the full flutter stack trace. so for example:

flutter build apk --debug --verbose